# Google speech API timeout time

Tags: node.js, timeout, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to use the Speech API client APIs in order to convert an audio file to text.

So far I have succeeded in converting a short audio clip, but now with a longer file (10 minutes) I get this error:

```
Retry total timeout exceeded before anyresponse was received
```

I've read in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits#content) that with async calls the maximum amount of minutes is 60 per call, and I have uploaded the file to Google Cloud Storage, as it's needed for files longer than 1 minute.

So I really don't see why I'm getting that error, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is a system timeout of 10 minutes.
[This is a known issue for other Google Cloud services](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#communicatewithinternet), but the fix suggested there did not work for me, I assume it's something else to be set when you run your code and start your connection.

Anyways, there is a workaround! You get the long running operation name, and then you stop your program. The operation will continue on the google server, and later you will fetch the result!

[As written in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize)

> Asynchronous Speech Recognition starts a long running audio processing operation.

I will refer to the `node.js`  sample here, similar concepts will apply for others.
So, when you get your response (do not use the promise version) pass it a callback, [like explained here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/speech/0.7.0/speech?method=startRecognition), and instead of

```
operation
    .on('error', function(err) {})
    .on('complete', function(transcript) {
      // transcript = "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge"
    });
```

just  do something like

```
console.log(operation)
```

take note of the operation name, and later on use [the operation method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/speech/0.7.0/speech?method=operation)

[You can test these on the google oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this issue, Google have now fixed this bug by removing the timeout value.  See https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs/pull/140/files
My speech api requests now work successfully after updating to the latest google-gax npm package.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper way to set timeout to be more than 10 minutes, so I modified `node_modules/google-gax/lib/longrunning.js` directly.
There is a varible called `backoffSettings` that holds timeout values, it is a call to a function `createBackoffSettings` in `node_modules/google-gax/lib/gax.js`.
Before I modified that variable it was like this:

```
backoffSettings =
        createBackoffSettings(100, 1.3, 60000, null, null, null, 600000);
```

I changed it to handle 1 hour timeout:

```
backoffSettings =
        createBackoffSettings(100, 1.3, 60000, null, null, null, 3600000);
```

The last parameter in `createBackoffSettings` function call is `totalTimeoutMillis` and as you see is by default 10 minutes.

If anyone knows a better way to handle it please share.
Hope it helps.